# Convert Keras model output into sparse matrix without forloop

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a pretrained `keras` model that has output with dimesion of `[n, 4000]` (It makes the classification on 4000 classes).

I need to make a prediction on the test data (300K observations).

But when I call method `model.predict(X_train)`, I get an `run-out memory error`, because I don't have enough RAM to store matrix with shape `(300K , 4000)`.

Therefore, it would be logical to convert the model output to a sparse matrix.

But wrapping the `predict method` into `scipy` function `sparse.csr_matrix` does not work (`sparse.csr_matrix(model.predict(X_train))`), because it first allocates space in the RAM for the prediction, and only then it converts into the sparse matrix.

I can also make a prediction on a specific batch of test data, and then convert it using `forloop`.
But it seems to me that this is not optimal and very resource-consuming way.

Please give me advice, can there be any other methods for converting the model output into a sparse matrix?

Comment: Calling a saved model in batches is commonplace - I could be wrong but can't help feeling that you're trying to solve a problem that at best doesn't need a solution and at worst just couldn't be solved. Surely even if you changed the model to output a sparse matrix (or any other more memory-efficient representation for that matter) it would still need the memory in it's penultimate layer?

Comment: I've thought that there are built-in `Keras` or `Tensoflow` methods for converting model output into a sparse matrix.

Comment: Sure - but all that would achieve is to ADD a new layer with the memory efficient representation to the end. The prediction would still need to use the memory for the large layer before it was converted

Comment: I think that the problem is in storing a huge `Numpy array` with predictions, and not in storing the weights of the model layers.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a `batch_size` parameter in the `predict()`?

If I get it correct the `n` means number of sample right?

Assume that you system ram is enough to hold the entire data but the VRAM is not.